# OSError: octave-cli not found, please see README

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, octave, oserror

I install oct2py with pip  and GNU Octave. When I use jupyter within VScode. When I run: import oct2py
I got the following error

> OSError: octave-cli not found, please see README

How can I solve this?

Comment: Do you have octave-cli on you path? https://github.com/blink1073/oct2py#installation

Comment: No. And I read github. I do not understand how to add it!!

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: Hi i use Win 10.

Comment: Hi i use Win 10. There is not octave.exe in C:\Program Files\GNU Octave\Octave-6.3.0 in my laptop.

Comment: Check this out http://blink1073.github.io/oct2py/source/installation.html#gnu-octave-installation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the exact same problem today and solved it as follows.

To get oct2py to work on windows 10:

1. install octave using the windows installer from the Octave website
2. `pip install oct2py`
3. edit the windows `PATH` variable to include octave.exe

   - For example on a recent installation a added the following to the windows `PATH`:
     `C:\Program Files\GNU Octave\Octave-6.4.0\mingw64\bin`
   - Check your `C:\Program Files\GNU Octave\` directory to find the correct version

Let me know how it goes!

Comment: it works. Many thank.