# Oct2Py - OSError: Octave not found, please see README - Mac M1

Tags: python, macos, anaconda, octave, apple-m1

I am aware of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69660733/oserror-octave-cli-not-found-please-see-readme) similar question, but that is on Windows and not for Mac M1, and their solution didn't work for me.

## Aim

I would like to be able to use the python package `oct2py`.

## Set Up and Problem

I have a new Mac M1. I have installed Anaconda using the 64-Bit (M1) Graphical Installer (316 MB).  I have created an environment `env-name`, activated it, and installed `oct2py` using the command `conda install -c conda-forge oct2py`. In Python, when running `from oct2py import octave` or simply `import oct2py` it fails with the following traceback

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/env-name/lib/python3.10/site-packages/oct2py/__init__.py", line 38, in <module>
    octave = Oct2Py()
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/env-name/lib/python3.10/site-packages/oct2py/core.py", line 83, in __init__
    self.restart()
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/env-name/lib/python3.10/site-packages/oct2py/core.py", line 533, in restart
    self._engine = OctaveEngine(stdin_handler=self._handle_stdin,
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/env-name/lib/python3.10/site-packages/octave_kernel/kernel.py", line 173, in __init__
    self.executable = self._get_executable()
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/env-name/lib/python3.10/site-packages/octave_kernel/kernel.py", line 472, in _get_executable
    raise OSError('octave not found, please see README')
OSError: octave not found, please see README
```

Comment: **Important** : According to [this](https://blink1073.github.io/oct2py/source/installation.html) link, the information for making `oct2py` work on MacOS is given [here](https://wiki.octave.org/Octave_for_macOS). However it doesn't work for me. I tried the Anaconda solution but running `conda install -c conda-forge octave` returns `PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:` etc

Comment: **Solution**: Installing it with brew has worked. All I had to do was to run `brew install octave`